# yuv to rgb in assembler

Tags: android, android-ndk

in

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
```

we get the data in YUV format. Now for converting to RGB I have used a converter in NDK. But it is still not fast enough.

So I found this:
http://www.roman10.net/effective-color-conversion-yuv-rgb-in-android-in-assembly/

which has this NDK method:
https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/blob/master/colorConversion/jni/test.c

but I do not know how to change it so it would accept the YUV byte array 'data' and return me an RGB int array?

Comment: Unfortunately, this [github collection](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/blob/master/colorConversion] uses is a conversion wrong formula. It is for YUV video, as defined in ITU-R BT.601 standard, with Y range of [16..235]. The camera image comes in YCbCr color space with Y range of [0..255]. The change is not very strong, but significant for the human eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write a JNI function similar to [`naGetConvertedFrame()`](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/blob/master/colorConversion/jni/test.c). The new function will have the following declaration:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_<name>_convert(JNIEnv * pEnv, jobject pObj, jobject pBitmap, jbyteArray jData, jint jWidth, jint jHeight)
```

The name of the function should reflect the name of the Java class that will declare this function as `native` method (see [RenderView.java](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/blob/master/colorConversion/src/roman10/tutorial/media/colorconversion/RenderView.java) as example). In Roman's example the *shared library* is loaded from another class, in [Main.java](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/blob/master/colorConversion/src/roman10/tutorial/media/colorconversion/Main.java) - but this `loadLibrary()` could be easily trasnferred into [RenderView.java](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/blob/master/colorConversion/src/roman10/tutorial/media/colorconversion/RenderView.java) file.

```
private static native void convert(Bitmap _bitmap, byte[] data, int _width, int _height);
```

Your function will be similar to the original example, only it will not read a file, but rather use [GetByteArrayElements()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237147/copying-a-byte-buffer-with-jni) to acquire **y**, **u**, and **v** pointers for the convertor.

Comment: I googled for GetByteArrayElemnts() but still do not know how to get Y U V values from a byte[]

Comment: The byte[] you receive from camera is semiplanar: first come Y bytes (_width*_height), and after that - (_width*_height/4) pairs of V and U bytes. As I can see, the library you intend to use only supports planar YUV (where U pixels and V pixels are separate). You will probably need to write your own function based on their code that takes semiplanar input.