# NV21 image to Bitmap conversion

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, android-image

I am trying to convert NV21 image from a LG 3D Android mobile to bitmap so I could send it over TCP socket to the computer.

At the moment it has to go through NV21->YUV->JPEG->ByteBuffer->Bitmap conversions which are just killing the CPU, is there a better way to cut out some of the conversions?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the computer could accept a NV21 buffer directly? If you insist on Bitmap format, note that the Android bitmap is not the same as Windows bitmap. If you need RGB on the Android side, you can use the recepy described here: [yuv to rgb in assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102576/yuv-to-rgb-in-assembler)

Comment: So your saying that it would be possible to send NV21 directly through TCP?

Comment: Absolutely. There is no barrier in TCP protocol against any pixel format. Whatever conversion you want can be as easily performed on the server. On the other hand, using JPG may be even more efficient: you loose device CPU time for compression, but gain a lot on network transport.

Comment: I see but the NV21 file would still need to be converted into some kind of byte buffer before sending? Network is not an issue it's the CPU time and power I need to save. It doesn't help that I am new to Java and Android

Comment: NV12 arrives from camera not as a file, but as byte array. Java can easily send a byte array through a TCP socket.

Comment: Oh thanks for info and sorry for my lack of knowledge I need to perform other calculations on the bitmap image itself, would be possible to Directly convert it to a bitmap from the camera byte array in a single stage instead of "NV21->YUV->JPEG->ByteBuffer->Bitmap".

Comment: My answer above includes a link where NV21 is converted to RGB on Android device. You can easily convert RGB byte array to Android bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RenderScript to convert NV21 to bitmap (or byte array) directly. On SGS3 with 720p images I was able to get about 20 FPS.

RenderSctipt is an Android subsystem that mostly runs as native to CPU code (and in some magical cases even on GPU) and is well parallelized to use all available cores.

You can read little more about it here - [Converting camera YUV-data to ARGB with renderscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509360/converting-camera-yuv-data-to-argb-with-renderscript/20788170#20788170)