# Executing ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRgb

Tags: android, renderscript

I want to convert a byte[] in Yuv into a byte[] in Rgb. The ScriptIntrinsic (ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRgb) is supposed to do this (based on this [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/java/tests/LivePreview/src/com/android/rs/livepreview/)).

Here's some code I have right now:

```
byte[] imageData = ...gatheryuvbuffer...

Type.Builder tb = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.createPixel(mRS, Element.DataType.UNSIGNED_8, Element.DataKind.PIXEL_YUV));
tb.setX(outputWidth);
tb.setY(outputHeight);
tb.setMipmaps(false);
tb.setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
Allocation ain = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, tb.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
ain.copyFrom(imageData);

Type.Builder tb2 = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.RGBA_8888(mRS));
tb2.setX(outputWidth);
tb2.setY(outputHeight);
tb2.setMipmaps(false);

// Allocation aOutBitmap = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, bitmap);
Allocation aOut = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, tb2.create(), Allocation.USAGE_IO_OUTPUT);
aOut.setSurface(null);

mYuvToRgb.setInput(ain);
mYuvToRgb.forEach(aOut);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputWidth, outputHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
aOut.copyTo(bitmap);
```

By the end of this script, I expect bitmap to contain something (I'm displaying it in an ImageView). But the bitmap shows up blank. What's wwrong with this code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the output allocation is created with USAGE_IO_OUTPUT but a surface is never attached.  I would try with (USAGE_SCRIPT & USAGE_SHARED) or just use the defaults.

Comment: That was it! I also had to remove the setSurface(null) call.