# Getting different errors for different platforms using Renderscript Support Library

Tags: android, eclipse, renderscript

I'm having different troubles trying to implement some code written in Renderscript for Android.
First let me say that all my SDK packages are up-to-dated to the 22.3 version, including the Ecplise ADT and Build-Tools 19.0.0.

My purpose is to implement some high-computational image algorithms on a wide range of Android platforms, possibly starting from API 8. For this, I've set a reference to the `renderscript-v8` library on my Ecplise project, while targeting the application to API 19.

I have two Android devices to test, the first is an Android 4.3 (API 18), the second comes with Android 2.2 (API 8). I'm experiencing different exceptions when running this piece of code, that calls [ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.html) (code is partially taken from [Executing ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRgb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435680/executing-scriptintrinsicyuvtorgb) question):

```
/* --------------
   global vars */

private RenderScript rs;
private ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB rs_YUVtoRGB;
private Allocation rs_YUVtoRGB_in;
private Allocation rs_YUVtoRGB_out;  

/* --------------
in constructor... */

this.rs = RenderScript.create(this.getContext());
this.rs_YUVtoRGB = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(this.rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

Type.Builder tb_in = new Type.Builder(this.rs, Element.createPixel(this.rs, Element.DataType.UNSIGNED_8, Element.DataKind.PIXEL_YUV));
tb_in.setX(prevWidth);
tb_in.setY(prevHeight);
tb_in.setMipmaps(false);
tb_in.setYuvFormat(this.camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat());
this.rs_YUVtoRGB_in = Allocation.createTyped(this.rs, tb_in.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

Type.Builder tb_out = new Type.Builder(this.rs, Element.RGBA_8888(this.rs));
tb_out.setX(prevWidth);
tb_out.setY(prevHeight);
tb_out.setMipmaps(false);
this.rs_YUVtoRGB_out = Allocation.createTyped (this.rs, tb_out.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

/* --------------
launching the script... */

// byte[] raw... // a YUV image

this.rs_YUVtoRGB_in.copyFrom(raw);
this.rs_YUVtoRGB.setInput(this.rs_YUVtoRGB_in);
this.rs_YUVtoRGB.forEach(this.rs_YUVtoRGB_out);

int[] framePixels = new int[previewSize.width * previewSize.height];
this.rs_YUVtoRGB_out.copyTo(framePixels);  // final RGB converted image
```

Eclipse manages to compile it (it should mean that the library is well referenced), but...

Android 4.3 fails at : `Type.Builder tb_in = new Type.Builder(this.rs, Element.createPixel(this.rs, Element.DataType.UNSIGNED_8, Element.DataKind.PIXEL_YUV));` with `Unsupported DataKind`

```
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494): android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Unsupported DataKind
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.renderscript.Element.createPixel(Element.java:911)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.support.v8.renderscript.ElementThunker.createPixel(ElementThunker.java:224)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.support.v8.renderscript.Element.createPixel(Element.java:832)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at com.lag.appprj.CameraPreview.setupCamera(CameraPreview.java:167)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at com.lag.appprj.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:86)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:571)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:833)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1860)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
11-24 11:17:57.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
```

While on Android 2.2 it fails in the init phase: `Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library RSSupport not found`

```
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lag.appprj/com.lag.appprj.CaptureActivity}: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library RSSupport not found
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048): Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library RSSupport not found
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:945)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:982)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:968)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at com.lag.appprj.CameraPreview.<init>(CameraPreview.java:80)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at com.lag.appprj.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:34)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-24 11:45:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

The error with createPixel() is an actual bug in ElementThunker.java. It is missing a case for PIXEL_YUV, so it ends up returning null instead of the appropriate type. I will fix this in AOSP and for a future SDK release. (Patch is at https://android-review.googlesource.com/70810).

As far as the library load issue, I believe on your other SO question you noticed that your Application.mk file was not building for all architectures (and hence not bundling the appropriate shared libraries). The reason that it works on 4.3 is that 4.3 has a copy of libRSSupport.so automatically (although it really shouldn't). Older devices will obviously not have a default /system/lib/ copy of that .so, so they will always fail to load it unless your build actually packages it up with the apk.

Comment: Ran into the `PIXEL_YUV` bug as well. I guess not many people are using it yet for it to go unnoticed for so long.